# How to quickly open a resource file by hovering on the file name in the code

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Suppose a Qt qmake project has a source with a following line of code:

```
loadTxt(":/libraryNotes.txt");
```

If I want to open the "libraryNotes.txt" files in the target's resources, I need to go the "Projects" tab, open the "Resources", and look for the file, then click and open it.

Is there any shortcut to do it directly from the code editor pane, when the mouse cursor or text cursor is over the filename? I'm thinking of a way similar to pressing F2 to follow the symbol to its declaration/definition.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be supported in Qt Creator 3.2.2 at least. But it shouldn't be too hard to add, most of the support code is already there.